# Scheme language: merge two numbers

Tags: list, merge, numbers, scheme

How can I merge two integers from a list into one? (in Scheme)
Example:
'(11 223) -> 11223

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that the list has exactly two elements, and that both are numbers:

```
(define (merge-numbers lst)
  (let ((1st (number->string (first  lst)))
        (2nd (number->string (second lst))))
    (string->number (string-append 1st 2nd))))
```

It works as expected:

```
(merge-numbers '(11 223))
> 11223
```

Alternatively, without using a `let`:

```
(define (merge-numbers lst)
  (string->number
   (string-append
    (number->string (first  lst))
    (number->string (second lst)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my original answer from Jan 25 '12 at 3:05. It only handles the given test. It was a mindless answer, sorry.

```
(define (merge ls) 11223)    
(merge '(11 223))
```

This is my new answer that handles all cases when passed a list of numbers. Thank you blubberdiblub for the pointer!
    ; list of zero or more strings -> string
    (define (merge-numbers ns)
      (if (null? ns) ""
            (let ((first-n (number->string (car ns)))
                  (rest-ns (cdr ns)))
              (string-append first-n (merge-numbers rest-ns)))))

```
(merge-numbers '(11 223))
(merge-numbers '())
(merge-numbers '(1))
(merge-numbers '(1 2))
(merge-numbers '(1 2 3))
(merge-numbers '(1 2 3 4))
(merge-numbers '(1 2 3 4 5))

"11223"
""
"1"
"12"
"123"
"1234"
"12345"
```

Since the original question probably meant that the result should be a number, and this results in a string, then `string->number` needs to be used to get the final answer. Thank you again blubberdiblub for an explanation of what the poster probably meant, I had missed it.

Comment: How does hard-coding the answer solve the problem for other cases?

Comment: Yes, that's much better, thanks for editing your answer :)
You may want to point out that the result might have to be run through `(string->number)` if a number is desired as opposed to a string (there are no double quotes in the original question, so it's very likely that the OP wanted a numeric result).

Comment: Thank you for again for the pointer blubberdiblub. While attempting to improve my answer I ended up with Mayer Goldberg's answer! I will add that note.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to write this procedure, depending on what you plan for it. For example, if the list might contain more than two numbers (in the future?) then you can write it as follows:

```
(define merge-numbers
  (lambda (s)
    (string->number
      (apply string-append
        (map number->string s)))))
```

So now you can type:

```
> (merge-numbers '(4 9 66 33 555 1))
4966335551
```

If there's a real reason why you want the number two, then I think the use of the procedure `format` would be more readable:

```
(define merge-two-numbers
  (lambda (s)
    (string->number
      (format "~a~a"
        (car s)
        (cadr s)))))
```

etc.