# Turn string into number in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I used `read` to get a line from a file. The documentation said `read` returns `any`, so is it turning the line to a string? I have problems turning the string `"1"` to the number `1`, or `"500.8232"` into `500.8232`.  I am also wondering if Racket can directly read numbers in from a file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out their [documentation search](http://docs.racket-lang.org/search/index.html), it's complete and accurate. Conversion functions usually have the form of `foo->bar` (which you can assume takes a `foo` and returns a `bar` constructed from it).

You sound like you're looking for a function that takes a `string` and returns a `number`, and as it happens, `string->number` does exist, and does pretty much exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was answered in another question:

[Convert String to Code in Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318952/convert-string-to-code-in-scheme)

NB: that converts any s-expression, not just integers.  If you want just integers, try:

```
string->number
```

Which is mentioned in

[Scheme language: merge two numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8954994/scheme-language-merge-two-numbers)

HTH