# Converting String to integer in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

How can I convert a string of digits to an integer ?
I want "365" to be converted to 365.

What I have tried,
string->list then char->integer, but this returns ASCII value of that integer, how can I get that integer ?

Please help.

Comment: `(string->number "365")`

Comment: Possible duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956789/read-number-in-or-something-can-turn-string-e-g-1-to-integer-1-in-racket/8956947#8956947)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try: `string->number`

```
> (string->number "1234")
1234
```

Comment: ahha, i didn't try this. I was going by some long way, anyways Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23027030/how-can-i-convert-a-string-into-exact-number-in-scheme-lisp

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution to parse integers from strings:

```
#lang typed/racket

(: numerical-char->integer (-> Char
                               Integer))
(define (numerical-char->integer char)
  (let ([num (- (char->integer char) 48)]) ; 48 = (char->integer #\0)
    (if
     (or (< num 0) (> num 9))
     (raise 'non-numerical-char #t)
     num)))

(: string->integer (-> String
                       Integer))
(define (string->integer str)
  (let ([char-list (string->list str)])
    (if (null? char-list)
        (raise 'empty-string #t)
        (foldl
         (λ([x : Integer] [y : Integer])
           (+ (* y 10) x))
         0
         (map numerical-char->integer char-list)))))
```