# Racket: Mapping from a k-tuple to an n-tuple

Tags: tuples, racket, slice

suppose we are given a 4-tuple (1,2,3,"cookies") and like to map it to a smaller tuple (1,2,3). How can this mapping be achieved? Is there something like a 'slice' function as in e.g. python?

Also another question in this context: how can string like e.g. "1.5" be converted into a float 1.5? Is there something like a 'toFloat' function?
--> found here a solution. My apologies for the insufficient research in stackoverflow. (see: [Turn string into number in Racket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956789/turn-string-into-number-in-racket))

Thank you for any hints

Answer (score 2):

You could always create your own function, a sort of "my-4-tuple-to-3-tuple" function that just makes a new tuple based on the old one. This is bad if you have a lot of different 4 tuples though because it's not a very generic solution.

For example... if you represent your tuple as a list.

```
(define (4tuple-to-3tuple 4tuple)
    (list (first 4tuple) (second 4tuple) (third 4tuple))
```

Comment: Could you improve the code so it better suits the k-vs-n case? As it stands, this solution is too ad-hoc and I feel like the quality is improper of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I have no actually used it on a decimal but you can use 
(string->number "1.5") it should work, however there might be a number to real or nunber to float tho

Answer (score 1):

Use `drop` and `take`.

If you need to remove something from the end of a list, do something like this:

```
 `(reverse (drop (reverse xs) 5)`
```

Use `rest` to remove a single element:

```
 `(reverse (rest (reverse xs))`
```

Note that single linked lists are a bad representation choice if you need to manipulate the end of the list often.

To convert a string into a number, use `string->number`.

Docs on `drop`:
  http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=drop

Docs on `string->number`:
  http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html?q=string-%3Enumber

Answer (score 1):

1. use **vector** instead of **tulip**
2. use `vector-copy` to get splice
3. the link to vector: http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/vectors.html